# Use chisel to implement a relatively large-scale project, how to check the progress of done elaborating

Tags: chisel

I am using chisel to implement a project that needs to call many of the same modules, and I am using a for loop to implement it. There is no problem with the compilation of the project, but it has been in the process of 'Done elaborating'. Using chisel will generate fir files, and then verilog, I want to know where to check the intermediate files in the 'Done elaborating' process.

```
[info] [0.002] Elaborating design...
[info] [3.443] Done elaborating.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you're invoking Chisel, you can turn up the log-level which should print about the progress through FIRRTL. On the command-line, this is done with `-ll info`.

As for "where" to look for the files, they should all be written to the target directory. The default is your current working directory; it can be set with `-td <directory>` on the command-line.

Comment: Thank you, the verilog generated by chisel can be divided into "[info] [0.003] Elaborating design..." and "[info] [3.768] Done elaborating." and "[success] Total time: 18 s".The target library will only be updated when the third step is completed. I want to know if some files will be generated between the second and third steps

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood, between `[success]` and the end is when files are written. That is weirdly slow. What version of Chisel are you using and how are you invoking Chisel?

Comment: I use chisel3.3 version, and the calling method is sbt. "sbt -v "test:runMain $args""

Comment: SBT has a fairly large startup time. How long does it take if you run the command in an SBT shell? ie. Run just `$ sbt` then when the interactive shell pops up, run `> test:runMain $args`. In any case, with default invocation, FIRRTL runs after `Done elaborating` (and it does a lot), more prints should show up if you add `-ll info` to your command-line arguments.